# i have activity which fetches data from message.java class and will be pushing data to firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here 's my main activity and i did get values from Name,Department and Phone

and i created Message.java class and refering the name,department,phone
then i did the same with my listview code.my problem is i can't

get the data pushed to firebase. after adding the listview code i cannot push
the data to firebase. before it would push name,department,phone to uid in firebase.

how do i push my listview data with my existing data as name,department,phone and my listview data to firebase

```
         final ListView myList =(ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView);
                final EditText Name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
                final EditText Department=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4dept);
                final EditText Phone=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText5phone);
                Button Add=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2Add);
                String name, department, phone;
                String[] listContent = {
                        "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
                };

                @Override
                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
                    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                    final DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReferenceFromUrl("https://myapp-91512.firebaseio.com/rohan");

                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, listContent);
                    myList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
                    myList.setAdapter(adapter);

                    Add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            name = Name.getText().toString();
                            department = Department.getText().toString();
                            phone = Phone.getText().toString();

                            Name.setText("");
                            Department.setText("");
                            Phone.setText("");

                            String selected = "";
                            int cntChoice = myList.getCount();
                            SparseBooleanArray sparseBooleanArray = myList.getCheckedItemPositions();
                            for (int i = 0; i <= cntChoice; i++) {
                                if (sparseBooleanArray.get(i)) {
                                    selected = myList.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
                                    Message message = new Message(name, department, phone,selected);
                                    myRef.push().setValue(message);

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    };
            }
```

Comment: i don't know how help me this

Comment: I tried to make your question more readable by adding some punctuation. But it is still unclear to me what you're saying and what the problem is. Can you try again to tell what your problem is with this code?

Comment: what is the error  log what kinda issue you are facing ?